# Autoresizing on adding subview

Tags: iphone, ios8, xcode6

I have an Application that is not using storyboard, but uses traditional xibs. And when I was adapting it to iPhone6/+ I noticed that when I add views from one view controller as a subview of view from another viewController it is resized but it shouldn't.

I have created test app to reproduce this issue so here is some code:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
    self.window!.rootViewController = ViewController(nibName:"ViewController", bundle : NSBundle.mainBundle())
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible();
    return true
}


class SubViewController: UIViewController
{
     override func viewDidLoad()
    {
         self.view.frame = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds

         println("viewDidLoad view. frame\(self.view.frame) screen bounds \(UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)")
               // => viewDidLoad view. frame(0.0,0.0,320.0,568.0) screen bounds (0.0,0.0,320.0,568.0)
}

class ViewController: UIViewController
{
      var subViewController : SubViewController?

     override func viewDidLoad()
     {
          super.viewDidLoad()
         // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

         self.subViewController = SubViewController(nibName:"SubViewController", bundle : NSBundle.mainBundle())

         self.view.addSubview(self.subViewController!.view)

         println("super view. frame\(self.view.frame) screen bounds \(UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)")
             //=>super view. frame(0.0,0.0,600.0,600.0) screen bounds (0.0,0.0,320.0,568.0)
     }

     override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() 
     {
         super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
     }
}
```

I use XCode6 GM and iOS8 GM.
If I set frame in subViewController's viewWillAppear it sets Ok, but still I want to figure out what causes such behavior?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the way to turn off that behavior I just had to set AutoresizingMask of mine subviews to None:

```
   [self.view setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingNone];
```

My suggestion that when I was adding my subview to another view in viewDidLoad it had wrong frame in that moment. So when proper frame for superview was set it applied autoresizing mask to it subviews that caused troubles.